# Spring basic security (need to validate authentication info of consumer before call reach to endpoint.)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I have implemented spring basic security authentication mechanism along with rest api endpoint. Let's say if someone is consuming my endpoint by passing auth info (user, key) along with header and for some reason i want to validate that header (user and key) info in my controller before endpoint call execution logic then how can I get that info?

Does it will work if i try to create header object and try to get?

Spring basic security code and end point is already created

Comment: Maybe this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-http-headers

Comment: You should create own filter and register it before authentication filter. https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-security-before-authentication-filter-examples

Comment: @PeterMmm I have referred your link and tried but it is not giving me header info of consumer (who is invoking my api with that basic auth info) rather it is giving me header details info of my api iteself.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar I have gone through your link and understood code but in my case I am not using any login form for logged in and I am using simple basic spring security so does it still work in case if I try first option "1. Simple Before Authentication Filter Configuration" from shared link ?

Comment: Yes. It should work. Your filter will be called before Basic Authentication done.

Comment: @DhavalGajjar i have applied simillar approach as point 1 from your link.  For me attempt authentication function code is not getting execute , i tried to debug it is not going to that line .   Can you pls provide me code snippet for my requirement like my end point is (http://sp/bal) and username:test and password : welcome123. (if someone consuming this end point with this auth info then very first i want to take password From header and compare with custom logic (gcpsecret=Welcome123)